# drawing alpha transparent rectangles to PDF from PHP

Tags: php, pdf-generation, alpha-transparency

I am currently using FPDF to generate PDF files. What I would need is to draw alpha-transparent rectangles (say with opacity 0.5) on top of an image.

I cannot find how to do this in FPDF, since `SetDrawColor` and `SetFillColor` (which are used to draw the rectangles) only take RGB arguments, no alpha value. So they automatically completely cover images or lines placed there with `Image` or `Line`.

How can I generate PDF files from PHP that have semi-transparent colored rectangles on top of a given background image and/or on top of a given set of (dashed/full) lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suddenly bumped into the answer: apparently, transparency is not stored on the color level in PDFs, but on the object level. And this add-on provides functionality for it: http://fpdf.org/en/script/script74.php